Creating table using phpmyadmin gives error
I am using the SQL tab to paste it into a database.
The statement:
CREATE TABLE qwerty_associations (
id int(11) NOT NULL,
context varchar(50) NOT NULL,
key char(32) NOT NULL
) ;
The error:
1 errors were found during analysis.
A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "NOT NULL" at position 108)

Please help.
I am new at this thing.

Your column named key conflicts with a reserved keyword. Either give the column some different name, or enclose it in back-ticks. See more details in the linked duplicate question.

Thank you very much. Your suggestion worked. I will remember to check for all reserved words in the future.
